# tab menu with dropdown issues with background image

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu that when I rollover a dropdown appears. The only problem is the background images of my main list also shows as the background of the submenu list.

Below is my css to assign the tab background on rollover. But I am assuming that since tech the user is still rolling over that `<li>` the tab background shows on all the sub `<li>`

CSS:

```
#main_menu ul li:hover a {
  background: url(images/right_tab_bg.png) top right no-repeat;
  color: #578ba0;
}

#main_menu ul li:hover a span {
  background: url(images/left_tab_bg.png) top left no-repeat;
}
```

Is there a way to tell the above css to only effect the parent `<a>` or `<span>`?

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific with your selectors via direct descendant selector (I am assuming that the ul that is the top level list is a direct descendant of whatever `#main_menu` is):

```
#main_menu > ul > li:hover > a /* select only the parent li's a */
#main_menu > ul > li li a /* select any child li's a, excluding the top level li */
```